# 10.8 Is there a way to jump to the top or bottom of current page when viewing a PDF in Preview?

Tags: macos, pdf, scrolling, pdf-reader, preview.app

To be clear, I am not asking for  function right, which sends me to the end of document  or space, which scrolls one screen height. If I am viewing page 31, I want to jump so that the top of 31 is at the top of my viewer, or the bottoms of 31 is at the bottom. I read a lot of articles on my macbook, and the pages are always to long for single page viewing, so I have to manually scroll through them, which is annoying and bad more my flow.

If there's no answer to my exact question, is there a way to scroll down a fixed amount that isn't a whole screen-height? Is there another PDF viewer that has the functionality I want? Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I usually browse through pages with <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>.

If you're somewhere in the middle of page 31, then going back a page (with <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>) and going to the next page (with <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>) will get you to the top of page 31.

I do not think there is anything like this for jumping to the bottom of a page.

Comment: Hmm. Cmd → isn't doing anything for me. What version of preview are you using and what OS? Also, what view setting are you in (e.g. continuous scroll, single page...)?